# What type of material can I use to make a model used for medical ultrasound practice?

Tags: material-science

I’m attempting to make a model for medical professionals to practice ultrasound guided procedures. What substances or materials would be adequate to project a picture similar to human tissue? I have a few ideas but want to pick your brains. Thank you

Comment: Ballistic gel?....

Comment: My guess is that the ultrasound will respond to impedance mismatches in the subject. In this case that would be the speed of sound. At the threshold between 2 substances with different speeds of sound, there will be some reflection, which is what I believe the ultrasound picks up.

Answer (score 1):

There is a substance called *ballistic gel* that is used by bullet manufacturers to shoot bullets into, to test their behavior when passing through flesh. Since it is designed to mimic the bodies of large mammals, perhaps it would work for your purposes.

it is sold as a dry powder to which water is added, after which it sets up like very stiff jell-o. By adding lumps of stuff like barium sulfate to it, you can vary its density locally and thereby get ultrasound reflections off it.

Comment: This was the first thought that came to my mind, too.

Comment: Came to me much earlier...